# Populate 2nd drop down based on first drop down result

Tags: javascript, php

I know this question have been asked before,  however, I don't seem to know how to apply in my scenario. I got a table in `MySQL`,  called subject, which consists of subject name and subject level.

For instance:

```
Subject Name, Subject Level
 (Maths,P1)
 (English, P2)
 (Science,P1)
 (English,S3)
```

My question is,  if the user select Subject level in the first drop down,  how does the 2nd drop down shows the Subject name it consists?

For instance, If the user select P1 in the first drop down, it would only show Maths and Science.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try learning Ajax. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp

Comment: You would want to use Ajax in conjunction with a back-end script to do this. The ajax function will be attached as a listener on the first dropdown menu - when the user selects an item from the menu the ajax function sends the request to the backend script which constructs and executes an sql statement. The results of the query are sent back to the javascript function which processes that data using a calback function ( the callback would generate the content for the second menu ) ~ at least, that is one way to do it!

Comment: Any example for reference? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will now write down the process how it can be done and then you will have to find tutorials for parts you don't understand.

So:
1 Step: Get levels from database and generate dropdown list of levels:

```
 <select id="level">
  <option value="p1">p2</option>
  <option value="p2">p2</option>
 </select>
```

2 Step: Prepare select box for subjects:

```
<select id="subjects" style="display:none"> //this field should be hidden first
</select>
```

3 Step: Using jquery, add listener for "level" select box(It means that this function will be executed every time user selects any level(p1,p2...):

```
<script>
  $('#level').on('change', function() {  //this chunk of code will be executed every time user reselects level value
    var selected = $(this).val(); //this is the value of selected level

    //here starts ajax method to communicate with server
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "getSubjectByLevel.php",
    data: { level: selected } //level is variable that will passed to getSubjectByLevel.php. You can get it in php file using $_POST["level"] and according this value generate sql query that will return only subject with this "level". Then you will have to generate array out of these subjects and return using normal "echo ArrayName" statement.
    })
    .done(function( subjects ) { //subjects is array of subjects returned from getSubjectByLevel.php
      var selectBoxHtml = '';
      for(i =0; i< subjects.length; i++){
        selectBoxHtml += '<option value='+subjects[i]+'>'+subjects[i]+'</option>';
      }
      $("#subjects").html(selectBoxHtml);  //put generated select box options in prepared earlier subjects select box
      $("#subjects").show(); //appear subjects select box which was hidden initially
     });
  });
</script>
```

This is kind of general algorithm for achieving what you want. If you have questions about details or conceptual issues you can't understand fill free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a chained select menu using ajax to build the second dropdown menu. This methodology could be extended to include many dropdowns but this should give you a good idea of how to implement this. There is no sql involved in the example ~ just an emulation.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* 
        this might be a totally separate script in reality 
        but for demo purposes the ajax function will send the 
        requests to the same page that has the html form on.
        */

        /* 
            Here you would intercept the value being POSTed by the ajax function
            and construct then execute your sql. The response will then be sent back
            to the callback function.
        */

        $posted_value=$_POST['q'];

        for( $i=0; $i < 20; $i++ ) echo "<option value=$i>".$posted_value.'_'.$i;

        /* As it is the same page we want to stop here */
        exit();
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chained Select Menu using ajax</title>
        <script>

            /* Very basic ajax function */
            function ajax(m,u,p,c){
                /*
                    m=method
                    u=url
                    p=params {name:value}
                    c=callback
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call(this,xhr.response);
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post':
                        p=params;
                    break;
                    case 'get':
                        u+='?'+params;
                        p=null;
                    break;  
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }

            /* Event listener - attached to select menu */
            function getdata(n){
                ajax.call( this, 'POST', document.location.href,{ q:n }, cbgetdata );
            }

            /* callback function that processes response data */
            function cbgetdata(r){
                document.getElementById('menu_2').innerHTML=r;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='geronimo'>

            <h1>Chained Dropdown menus</h1>

            <select name='menu_1' onchange='getdata( this.value )'>
                <option value='AL'>AL</option>
                <option value='AK'>AK</option>
                <option value='AZ'>AZ</option>
            </select>

            <select name='menu_2' id='menu_2'></select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it solved the problem, or at least helped you solve the problem, perhaps you could accept the answer